# .htaccess %{REQUEST_URI} trailing slash and Zend Cache

Tags: php, zend-framework, .htaccess

I have a php caching system(based on Zend Static Cache) ... that creates static html files from dynamic pages. It uses the REQUEST_URI to create the file names.
For a  REQUEST_URI like this /somedir/otherdir/file.html 
it creates a file in the cached dir (on my server)  like this /cached/somedir/otherdir/file.html.

I then use htaccess to redirect future requests to the static file if it exists:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cached/%{REQUEST_URI}\.html -f
RewriteRule .* /cached/%{REQUEST_URI}\.html [L]
```

The problem I'm having is that when the REQUEST_URI ends in "/" (basicaly a directory) the cache generates a file named thedirectory.html.

So if the REQUEST_URI is /thedirectory/ ... I get a this file cached/thedirectory.html.

How would I go about redirecting such a request to the right file.

Thanks.
PS: I've basically followed  [this article](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=fr&u=http://blog.developpez.com/lucas-corbeaux/p9647/php/zend-framework/zend-cache-backend-static-zend-framework/&ei=ivAvT_jKCK6F0QH9qoXnCg&sa=X&oi=translate&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCkQ7gEwAA&prev=/search?q=%255BPHP%255D%255BWeb%255D%2bMise%2ben%2bplace%2bd%2527un%2bcache%2bStatic%2bavec%2ble%2bZend%2bFramework&hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=pq6&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&prmd=imvns) to implement my cache. I'm using the Zend Cache files only on a custom php app.

### EDIT:

I guess there's no good way to make this work without editing the php files.
Here's how I use Zend Cache :

```
$tagCache = Zend_Cache::factory('Core', 'File', array('automatic_serialization' => true),
    array('cache_dir' => $cfg['instdir']. 'Cache_dir'));
    $cache = Zend_Cache::factory('Capture', 'Static', array(), array('public_dir' => $cfg['instdir']. 'Cached/',
    'tag_cache' => $tagCache)); 
    $id = bin2hex($name);
    $cache->start($id, array());
```

Does any one know what files are likely to hold the code for generating the cache file name? I've edited a couple of frontends,backends ..but nothing seems to be happening.

I'm trying to do something like(just before ZEND gets the REQUEST_URI ):

```
if(substr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],strlen($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])-1,1)=="/")
```

{

$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]=$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]."index.html";

}

too make the cache add a index.html file for directories.

Comment: Don't you mean `cached/thedirectory/.html`?

Comment: No php removes the / somewhere... I'm looking in the Zend files right now.

Comment: did you ever figure this one out @Iansen ? Having the same issue now.

Answer (score 1):

Try excluding the directories as below

```
#only if it is not a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cached/%{REQUEST_URI}\.html -f
RewriteRule .* /cached/%{REQUEST_URI}\.html [L]
```

**EDIT**

> I need a {REQUEST_URI} ending in / to redirect to a file that's exactly the {REQUEST_URI} without the last / (and a .html at the end)

Try adding this rule before any existing rules in your .htaccess

```
#redirect all requests with a trailing slash to the html versions
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$  $1.html [L,R=301]
```

Comment: it doesn't work because {REQUEST_URI} ends in / ...and my file doesn't ... it would redirect to somedir/.html ...but than is not even a correct file name.

Comment: I need a {REQUEST_URI} ending in / to redirect to a file that's exactly the {REQUEST_URI} without the last / (and a .html at the end)

Comment: thanks @Ulrich .... but I don't want to change the URLs ... permanently redirecting them to new ones.

Comment: @lansen If you want to skip redirects, drop the `R=301` i.e. change the rule to just `RewriteRule ^(.+)/$  $1.html [L] `